# Change EF 4.1 Code First Default DB Location

Tags: code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I'm working through the [Building an MVC 3 App with Code First and Entity Framework 4.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg685467) tutorial on MSDN and got stuck on "Also ***by default***, this database will be a SQL Express database with the name derived from the strongly typed name of the context and its file will be in the SQL Express default data folder."

If I want to change the default (e.g. to place the MDF file in my App_Data folder) how would I do that?  I will have several different contexts (one for each major functional area) and would like them all to live in the same database.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You define where the database lives using the web.config file connection settings.
You just have to make the Context Name = your connection string name so if the of you Context is MyContext you could define the location as below:

```
    <connectionStrings>
    <clear/>
        <add name="MyContext" 
         connectionString="Server=myServer;Database=MyDB;Uid=foo;Password=XXX; " 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
           />


  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: If I want all contexts to live in the same physical DB, would I just provide multiple entries with appropriate `name` elements and the same `connectionString` element?

Comment: I have never tried it, but yes  that sounds like it should work you will just have to becareful of your DB initialisation that it does not try to drop and create the DB for each context? i.e. you may haveto use  CreateDatabaseIfNotExists instead of DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges or DropCreateDatabaseAlways

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your second question...

"I will have several different contexts (one for each major functional area) and would like them all to live in the same database."

Why not try...

MyContext.cs

```
public partial class MyContext : DbContext
{
}
```

FooContext.cs

```
partial class MyContext
{
    public DbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
}
```

BarContext.cs

```
partial class MyContext
{
    public DbSet<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}
```

You'll end up with one context and one connection, but your code is split over multiple files.  Hopefully that's what you are trying to achieve.